# How to fix pod lib lint not recognising UIColor.label on iOS 13

Tags: swift, cocoapods, uicolor, swift5

I'm updating my pod to support dark mode on iOS 13. I'm using Swift 5.0 both in my podspec file and in my pod build settings. When running `pod lib lint` I receive an error that UIColor has no member 'label'.

- I've updated Cocoapods to the latest version (tried with both stable and --pre).
- Swift 5 is set both in my pod's built settings and in my podspec file.
- I have an `if #available(iOS 13.0, *)` checker at every instance where I use any of the new colours.

The project runs successfully on Xcode 11 beta GM.

I'm expecting `pod lib lint` to run successfully but I receive errors such as the following:

```
error: type 'UIColor?' has no member 'label'
```

Is there something I'm missing?

[image: Screenshot added]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing Command Line Tools to use Xcode 11.

1. Open Xcode 11
2. Open Preferences
3. Click the Location tab
4. Change Command Line Tools to use Xcode 11

[image: Xcode 11 Locations tab screenshot]

Comment: I get this error in xcode 10 and command line tools are setted to xcode 10... suggestions?

Comment: @Bored I don't think `UIColor.label` is available in Xcode 10. I think you'll need to update to Xcode 11 to use that

Comment: I know, but I'm working on an old mac mini (mid 2011) so I can't update the OS or xcode

Comment: Right.. then I just think that there's no way for you to use `UIColor.label` to be honest.